# Can I overclock an ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250? If so, how?

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking, ati-mobility-radeon

Can I overclock ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250? If so, how?

My laptop is a Dell M5010 (aka 15R) with AMD Phenom II N850 69°C Caspian 45nm Technology, with 8GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 665MHz (9-9-9-24).

Comment: Might I ask why you would ever want to overclock a laptop GPU?

Comment: can you ? yes. should you ? prolly not. laptops are well known for having very complex cooling issues and the extra heat may well push it over the edge. If you try this be sure to keep an eye on the temps of every componant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AMD GPU Clock Tool](http://www.techpowerup.com/downloads/1128/AMD_GPU_Clock_Tool_v0.9.8.html), which is supposed to work in conjunction with that card. Be careful doing this on a laptop though, ensure you watch your temperatures carefully.

This may not work though, as laptop GPUs cannot always be overclocked. The BIOS may not allow it, and you may need to mod it (not recommended).